# sum of series by recurrent formula

Tags: calculus

why $S_n = x(1+x^2+x^4+..x^{2n}) = x*\frac{1-x^{2n+2}}{1-x^2}$ and not $x*\frac{1-x^{2n}}{1-x^2}$?

in $(1+x^2+x^4+..x^{2n})$ we have $b_1=1$ and $q=x^2$ so $S_n$ is supposed to be equal to $\frac{1-x^{2n}}{1-x^2}$

Comment: $S_n=\frac{b_1(1-q^n)}{1-q}$

Comment: The sum $1+x^2+\ldots+x^{2n}$ contains $n+1$ terms and so you have to adjust your formula appropriately. That basically means replacing $n$ with $n+1$.

Comment: n+1 cause the first item is 1? so the nth item will be not $x^{2n}$ but $x^{2^{n+1}} = x^{2n+2}$?

Comment: the formula you posted in the comments gives the sum of the first $n$ terms of a geometric series. However, your sum contains $n+1$ terms. So you need to adjust your formula.

Comment: How do you count them? It's more confusing than i expected

Comment: just take small values of $n$ like $n=2,3$ or $4$ and count the terms

Comment: $S_3 = x + x^3 + x^5$ or maybe not.

Answer (score 0):

Set $$S_m = S_m(x)=\sum_{k=0}^m x^k$$
then
$$x\cdot S_m - S_m= \sum_{k=1}^{m+1} x^k - \sum_{k=0}^m x^k = x^{m+1} - 1$$
as all terms in the difference of the sums cancel, except two terms.  Hence
$$S_m(x) = \frac{x^{m+1}-1}{x-1}$$
Now the expression that you are interested in is $xS_n(x^2)$, so just plug that in.